# mvn error : androMDA project

Tags: maven, andromda

I am very new to maven and its functionality.

The below image shows the errors when I try to run the maven.

Please throw some light on what could be the error

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your `settings.xml` and the project's `pom.xml`?

Comment: I am sure they are too long for me to add as a comment, can you pelase let me know how to share

Comment: I meant you should edit the question to include them.

Comment: Hi they are too long to add culd you please let me know the sections of the files you want to look at

Comment: sorry its a typo eror, I wanted to ask youthe sections that you want to look at